# Return posts with most views in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm working on a feature that is supposed to pull in the top 8 most viewed posts from a database. The code I'm using isn't quite returning what I need and I'm not sure why this is happening. My database row name is `views`. The code I'm using is below:

```
$most_populars = \App\Post::where('status', '=', 'PUBLISHED')->get()->sortByDesc('views');
dd($most_populars);
```

When I use this, I get an array of 123 posts back which is what I expect. So next I use a foreach loop to get the views like this:

```
foreach ($most_populars as $most_popular) {
  dd($most_popular->views);  
}
```

When I use the dd() inside of the foreach loop, I get the post with the most views, but I only get the first one. Why is this? Shouldn't I be seeing the view count for 123 other posts? Any help I can get is a great help =) Thanks guys.

Comment: When you `dd()`, it kills the script at that point, so it will only ever show the first one. If you want all of the views, then echo it, log it, or get one of the object properties.

Comment: Get out! Well I just learned something new =) Feel free to throw that into a quick answer and I'll gladly give an upvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd()` will kill the script. The function itself looks like this:

```
function dd()
{
    array_map(function($x) { (new Dumper)->dump($x); }, func_get_args());

    die;
}
```

Note the `die` at the end. If you want to get each value, then echo it or log it.